Zoom Video SDK Crashing in Release Build for Flutter App
Description: I’m experiencing an issue with the Zoom Video SDK integrated into my Flutter app. The integration works perfectly in both debug and profile builds; however, the release build crashes upon opening the app. Occasionally, the debug console shows an error during SDK initialization with the following message:

var zoom = ZoomVideoSdk();
    InitConfig initConfig = InitConfig(
      domain: "zoom.us",
      enableLog: true,
    );
    zoom.initSdk(initConfig);


LERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sdkinit_failed, Init SDK Failed, null, null)
#0
#1 StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/services/message_codecs.dart:648:7)
MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18)
#2 ZoomVideoSdk.initSdk.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_zoom_videosdk/native/zoom_videosdk.dart:512:23)

I have updated the package versions to the latest release and replaced the API key and secret credentials, but the issue persists and the SDK is still not working
